# How do I print out a variable in the following scenario?

Tags: python-3.x

Here is the code in which I cant print out the list variable:

```
from typing import List, Any, Union


pylist: List[Union[str, Any]] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
o = pylist.copy()
while pylist != o:

    for i in range(len(pylist)):

        pylist.rotate(i)

        print(pylist)
```

Comment: You should include error tracebacks with your question if there was an error, but I reckon the answer below is what you're looking for. Also, in Python `list.rotate` does not exist but what is the goal of your for loop anyway?

Comment: i wanted to rotate a list until i got back the original list

Comment: Did the answer below help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not entering the while loop, since `pylist == o`